# download a torrent file from kickass torrent from linux cli

Tags: wget, curl, download, rtorrent

this one has been bugging me for a while and I cannot find any answer. In fact I usually get google results for cli torrent clients rather than what I want.

So `rtorrent` is notorious about crashing when fed with magnet links. So to circumvent that I want to download torrent files directly from the command line. More often than not kickass torrents provide torrents of interest (f.e. `slackware` dvds) but by right clicking and "copy link location" will provide a link of the sort:

> https://torcache.net/torrent/85922FBEE6DCE5E2F5491E16BCDD9E6E427BA5AA.torrent?title=[kat.cr]slackware64.14.2.iso

If I `wget` this link, I'll receive a corrupt file named

> "85922FBEE6DCE5E2F5491E16BCDD9E6E427BA5AA.torrent?title\=[kat.cr]slackware64.14.2.iso"

which does not load in `rtorrent` correctly.

`curl` also says:

> curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 86

Is there another command or some argument for `curl` or `wget` that I miss and which would correctly download the file?

thank you

Comment: looks like wget/curl are trying to guess filename from url, I would suggest using output file option and giving a decent filename.

Comment: @Archemar nope, this is like renaming it after downloading it. the file is somehow corrupt and I get the following from `rtorrent` : `Reading torrent file failed: "./[kat.cr]slackware64.14.2.iso.torrent" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I finally sat down and looked into the contents of the file. It appears that kickass torrents sends a `gzip`ed version of the torrent file and the browser quietly `gunzip`s it.

so I created the following download script to get the torrent files.

```
#!/bin/bash

torr_link="${1}"

#perl parses the link and keeps as torrent title whatever comes after the variable "title" in the link
torr_title=$( echo "${torr_link}" | perl -ne 's/(.*)title=(.*)/\2/g; print;' )
echo "downloading ${torr_title}"

wget -O "${torr_title}".torrent.gz "${1}"

gunzip "${torr_title}".torrent.gz
```

save it in a text file and pass the kickass torrent link as an argument.